# GPIO library for DHT11

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, adafruit, iio

I'm trying to read the data from my DHT11 sensor, which is connected to GPIO-12 (Pin-32). First, I wrote a Python script using the Adafruit_DHT library, but when I start the script, this error occurs. This is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amir-pi/Wetter_Projekt/Adafruit_Python_DHT-1.4.1/test1.py", line 8, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/amir-pi/Wetter_Projekt/Adafruit_Python_DHT-1.4.1/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 94, in read_retry
    humidity, temperature = read(sensor, pin, platform)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/amir-pi/Wetter_Projekt/Adafruit_Python_DHT-1.4.1/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 80, in read
    platform = get_platform()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/amir-pi/Wetter_Projekt/Adafruit_Python_DHT-1.4.1/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 63, in get_platform
    raise RuntimeError('Unknown platform.')
RuntimeError: Unknown platform.
```

I have tried multiple solutions, such as reinstalling the library, updating the library, or moving and starting the script from the Adafruit_DHT directory.

```python
import Adafruit_DHT

# Sensor-Typ und Pin konfigurieren (DHT11, Pin 32)
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
pin = 12

# Versuche, die Temperatur und Luftfeuchtigkeit vom Sensor zu lesen
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

# Überprüfe, ob die Daten erfolgreich gelesen wurden
if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    print('Temperatur={0:0.1f}°C Luftfeuchtigkeit={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))
else:
    print('Fehler beim Lesen der Daten vom Sensor. Versuche es erneut!')
```

Comment: The [Adafruit_DHT](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/) library was deprecated back in 2019. According to the README, "We are now only supporting the use of our CircuitPython libraries for use with Python. Check out this guide for info on using DHT sensors with the CircuitPython library: https://learn.adafruit.com/dht-humidity-sensing-on-raspberry-pi-with-gdocs-logging/python-setup". Your problem could simply be that the library is unmaintained. Trying following the documentation and using the CircuitPython library instead.

Comment: For Linux-based OS use in-kernel driver: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8-rc3/source/drivers/iio/humidity/dht11.c.